# VBA: Checking if Bloomberg BDH call is finished

Tags: vba, excel, bloomberg

Cells `A1:A20` contains Bloomberg BDH data. I'm looking for a way to copy-paste the entries of those cells in a different sheet.And then replacing the values with a BDH call.

This process is going to be looped for a large number of times, say `1500`.
(Thus making it very ineffective to use a `Application.OnTime Now` command)

Any suggestions?

Comment: You may link the cells instead of copy-paste to get the updated values.

Comment: I forgot to mention some details. Please see the updated description.

Comment: It is probably easier to query the data directly from the vba api and paste the result wherever you need it.

Comment: I agree, but this is a simplified version of the actual problem. There's more data involved, worksheet function and variables that makes it much easier to do it this way in the actual problem.